# clojure macro create || comparison?

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to create an || comparison with Clojure like other languages.

```
(defmacro ||
  [source & other]
  `(loop [s# [~source ~@other]]
     (println s#)
     (let [fs# (first s#)]
       (if fs#
         fs#
         (if (= (count s#) 1)
           fs#
           (recur (next s#)))))))
```

but this can't work. fs# value is quote data.

like this

```
(def a [1])
(defn b []
  (println 11111))

(|| (get a 0) (b))
```

I want the result to be 1, this is `(get a 0)` but the result is `(get a 0)` this is Expression, not a var. How do I create an || macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure's equivalent of `||` is the macro [`or`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or) . You can view its implementation [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L817).

If you want to use the symbol `||`, you can just alias the `or` macro:

```
(def #^{:macro true} || #'or)
```

You can then use either:

```
(or (get a 0) (b))
```

or

```
(|| (get a 0) (b))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your expected result, `(get a 0)` or `1`? On my machine ,the result of your code is `1`. I think that's nothing to do with macros. Before expanding the macro `(|| (get a 0) (b))`, `(get a 0)` and `(b)` will be evaluated and the macro just get arguments `1` and `nil`. If you want result of `(get a 0)`, you should use `(|| '(get a 0) (b))`